# Media is not overriding the original css

Tags: css, overriding, media

For some reason my @media doesn't override my original css. The thing it shows up in my inspector, but it is crossed. I made sure my media override is under my other css.

Css code:

```
#content div div:nth-child(even) p{
margin-left: 40px;
}



@media (max-width:880px){

 #content div div p {
     margin-left: 0;
     margin: 0;
 }
 }
```

screenshot of inspector: [Screenshot](http://gyazo.com/df3c7fd28548eea0a6ef08cc2593f918)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because the top selector is more specific than your new custom selector.

Try using the same selector:

```
#content div div:nth-child(even) p{
    margin-left: 0;
}
```

Or, less accepted in the community, use !important:

```
#content div div p{
    margin-left: 0!important;
}
```

Comment: Anytime man come find me if you need help with CSS.  Just don't make it a habit ;)

Comment: Can you select my answer please?

Comment: The use of !important is hackey

Comment: It says I have to wait  1 more minute before I can do that, I will in a sec :)

Answer (score 0):

Using !important is not the best approach, you should respecify the selector in the media query:

```
#content div div:nth-child(even) p{
    margin-left: 40px;
}

@media (max-width:880px){
     #content div div:nth-child(even) p {
         margin-left: 0;
         margin: 0;
     }
 }
```

Using [SASS](http://thesassway.com/intermediate/responsive-web-design-part-2) and @media bubbling is an even better approach.